# what's the purpose of using array initialize to null?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm wondering what's the purpose of using **array that initialized to null** 
and isn't **array immutable** can't be changed once it initialized?
here's an example

```
SomeClass[] b = null;
try {
  ObjectInputStream inputStream =
       new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("arrayfile"));
  b = (SomeClass [])inputStream.readObject();
  inputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: arrays are not immutable. They have a fixed length once they are initialized.

Comment: If the array is used after the `try` block then if it's never initialized (even to `null`) the compiler can complain about the use of an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers to this:

- A plausible reason for doing this is to ensure that `b` has been *definitely initialized*, either in the `catch` block for that `try`, or after the `try` / `catch`.  (If you don't do this, and you *use* `b` in one of theose places, you will get a compilation error.)
- The actual reason can only really be determined with complete certainly by asking the code's author.  (It could be that the author is following some so-called "best practice" ... that isn't.)

---

I should also point out that that your example code potentially leaks file descriptors.  The modern way to write it to not leak fds is:

```
SomeClass[] b = null;
try (
    ObjectInputStream inputStream =
        new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("arrayfile"))) 
{
    b = (SomeClass []) inputStream.readObject();
}
```

The old (pre-Java 7) way is to use a `finally` block to close the stream.